# Spark-Scala build.sbt libraryDependencies UnresolvedDependency

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i'm trying to import a dependency in my build.sbt file from here
https://github.com/dmarcous/spark-betweenness.

When i hover on the error it says:

> Expression type ModuleID must confirm to Def.SettingsDefinition in SBT file
>     Unresolved Dependency

I am new in scala so my question may be silly.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide the code that you use to add the dependency.

Comment: libraryDependencies += "com.centrality" %% "spark-betweenness" % "1.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

It is still unclear how your build configuration looks like, but the following `build.sbt` works (in the sense that it compiles and does not show the error that you mentioned):

```
name := "test-sbt"

organization := "whatever"

version := "1.0.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.7"

libraryDependencies += "com.centrality" %% "spark-betweenness" % "1.0.0"
```

Alternatively, if you have a multi-project build, it could look like this:

```
lazy val root = project
  .settings(
    name := "test-sbt",
    organization := "whatever",
    version := "1.0.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.10.7",
    libraryDependencies += "com.centrality" %% "spark-betweenness" % "1.0.0"
  )
```

However, you're probably going to find that it still does not work because it cannot resolve this dependency. Indeed, this library does not seem to be available neither in Maven Central nor in jcenter. It is also very old - it appears to only be published for Scala 2.10 and a very old Spark version (1.5), so most likely you won't be able to use it with recent Spark environments (2.x and Scala 2.11).